# Is there any way a usb device can identify the usb host operating system?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

Is there any way for the USB device to know if it is connected to a Windows or to a Mac without the installation of a third party software?

Maybe there is a way to "ask" a question via USB and figure that out from the USB Host reply?

Comment: If it is a device of your own design then presumably you'll also be writing the system drivers for it, in which case yes the driver can be designed in such a way that it tells the device what OS the driver is compiled for.  Otherwise, if you're just asking generically about any off-the-shelf USB device that already exists, then no, that is not possible generically.  A generic device will be able to find out some things about the host hardware's USB hub but very little more than what is fed to it by the system driver.

Comment: The 'U' in USB is for "universal" so the devices don't care about the OS and would never need to know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a valid EE question.

Comment: "USB Fingerprinting" is the magic search term. 
See for example https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6159115/ Seems to me that the physical layer and timing aspects of doing the fingerprinting may very well be as much EE as CS.

Answer (score 1):

The USB specification doesn't provide any way to do this. You should also consider the USB host may not be running an operating system at all if it's an embedded device.

You could design your own protocol on top of USB which allowed you to find out if you needed to.